# Integral from infinite sum

Tags: calculus, matrices, limits, functions, summation

I am trying to find if there is a way of turning the following sum into an integral:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{x}\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{C^{k}}{x^2+x}\right)$$
I have looked into Riemann sums however I wasn't able to do it with this sum, however this could well be I didn't understand them fully.

Answer (score 0):

This is a geometric series. Assuming that $\|C\|<1$,
$$\begin{split}
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{x}\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{C^{k}}{x^2+x}\right) &= \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac 1 {x^2 + x}\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{x}C^{k}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac 1 {x^2 + x}\operatorname{tr}\left(C(I-C^x)(I-C)^{-1}\right)\\
&= \operatorname{tr}\left(C(I-C)^{-1}\right)\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac 1 {x^2+x}\\
&=0
\end{split}$$

Comment: What if $||C|| $is bigger than 1?

Comment: Then we can't say that the series converges.